# Worksheet Function "Filter" get data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get all the values of a column based on a matching value through the filter function.

So far I have a form, please just pay attention to `label4`**(Name: LBL_CODIGO_SH)**, `label5`**(Name: LBL_CODIGO_SH)** and `combobox`**(Name: ComboBox3)**.
[image]

My code is executed when clicking on the **"Buscar"** button:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tabla As ListObject
    Dim codigo As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Relacion")
    Set tabla = ws.ListObjects("Tabla3")
    codigo = Me.LBL_CODIGO_SH.Caption & "_" & Me.LBL_CODIGO_TH.Caption

    Me.ComboBox3.List = WorksheetFunction.Filter( _
                        tabla.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, _
                        Evaluate(tabla.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value & "=" & codigo) _
                    )
End Sub
```

I run my program and it gives me error 13.
[image]

I think I'm skipping code in the **"Filter" function of the spreadsheet**.

I would like to get the results in a combobox and also in an array variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Address property of the DataBodyRange object, instead of the Value property . . .

```
Me.ComboBox3.List = WorksheetFunction.Filter( _
                        tabla.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, _
                        ws.Evaluate(tabla.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Address & "=" & codigo) _
                    )
```

However, if you're filtering for a string, you'll need to wrap your criteria within quotes . . .

```
Me.ComboBox3.List = WorksheetFunction.Filter( _
                        tabla.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, _
                        ws.Evaluate(tabla.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Address & "=""" & codigo & """") _
                    )
```

Note that the Address property returns the range reference as a string, which is used to build another string to form an expression.  This concatenated string is passed to the Evaluate method, which evaluates the expression, and returns the array of booleans needed for the second argument of `WorksheetFunction.Filter`.

For additional information regarding the Address property, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144076);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Comment: @Domenico Thank you very much the second option if it worked for me. Could you help me answer a question please? I thought putting the `Value` property would look up each value in the range cell by cell, but I was wrong, so what does the `Address` property do? Could you explain how it works?
And thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome.  The `Address` property simply returns the range reference as a string.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144076);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) for additional information.